# a question on oriented bundles and Euler class

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, geometric-topology, characteristic-classes, obstruction-theory

In Characteristic classes, J. Milnor, J. Stasheff, Prop. 9.7, it is proved that:

if the oriented vector bundle $\xi$ possesses a nowhere zero cross section, then the Euler class $e(\xi)=0$.

I want to ask

(1). whether the converse is true?

(2). In particular, if $\xi$ is a complex line bundle, whether the converse is true?

Answer (score 2):

See the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105966/how-to-interpret-the-euler-class), which answer your question and tell you a good deal more about closely related stuff and intuition for questions like this one.

Comment: So the short answer is yes or no for 1) and 2)?

Comment: Did you read the answer to the linked question by Akhil Mathew? It directly addresses this.

Comment: The 1) is no. The 2) is also no. True?