# How to tell the tangent bundle of $S^2$ from the bundle $S^2\times$ $y-z$ plane?

Tags: differential-geometry, characteristic-classes

Intuitively, I would like to say that the tangent bundle of $S^2$ and the bundle ($S^2\otimes \rm{y-z\ plane}$) is different. By the latter I mean a product bundle, embedding in $R^3$ it is equivalent to attaching a yz plane at each point of $S^2$.

Is there a type of characteristic class that tells these two apart? The Pontryagin class for both is $0$ as it is $2d$ by $2d$.

Comment: The latter has a nonzero vanishing vector field, the former has not.

Comment: @Didier what is a nonzero vanishing vector field? You mean nowhere-vanishing section? Is there a type of characteristic class that can tell these apart?

Comment: The euler class measures that.

Comment: @Alex Sorry, I meant a nowhere-vanishing vector field

Comment: @ArcticChar could you please elaborate?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105966/how-to-interpret-the-euler-class). If the bundle has a nowhere-vanishing section, it's euler class is zero.

Comment: As Didier hints, nonisomorphism follows from the Hairy Ball Theorem. In fact more is true: The total spaces of the bundles are not even diffeomorphic: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1323740/are-t-mathbbs2-and-mathbbs2-times-mathbbr2-different